# Examine if a value is in an interval using R

Tags: r, dplyr

Having the following vector:

```
t <- c(2, 6, 8, 20, 22, 30, 40, 45, 60)
```

I would like to find the values that fall between the following intervals:

```
g <- list(c(1,20), c(20, 40))
```

The desired output is:

```
1, 20 c(2, 6, 8)
20, 40 c(20, 22, 30)
```

Using the dplyr library, I do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
for(i in t){
    for(h in g){
        if(between(i, h[[1]], h[[2]])==TRUE){print(c(i, h[[1]], h[[2]]))}
}}
```

Is there a better way of doing this in R?

Comment: another one `lapply(g, function(x) t[findInterval(t, x) == 1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can loop over the `list` 'g' and extract the 't' elements based on the first and second values by creating a logical vector with `>/<` and extract the elements of 't'

```
lapply(g, function(x) t[t >= x[1] & t  < x[2]])
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 6 8

[[2]]
[1] 20 22 30
```

Comment: A question, is it possible to get the vector indices instead of values? That is to get 1, 2, 3 instead of 2, 6, 8?

Comment: I think `lapply(g, function(x) which(t >= x[1] & t  <= x[2]))` works fine

Answer (score 3):

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map(g,~keep(t,between(t,.[1],.[2])))

[[1]]
[1]  2  6  8 20

[[2]]
[1] 20 22 30 40
```

Answer (score 2):

You may find `findInterval()` from base R useful:

```r
g <- c(1, 20, 40)
t <- c(2, 6, 8, 20, 22, 30, 40, 45, 60)
findInterval(t, g)
#> [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

So `t[1]`, `t[2]` and `t[3]` are in the first interval, `t[4]`, `t[5]` and
`t[6]` in the second, and `t[7]`, `t[8]` and `t[9]` the third (meaning that
these values are bigger than the right end point of the second interval.)
If you had values lower than one they would be labelled by 0:

```r
t2 <- c(-1, 0, 2, 6, 8, 20, 22, 30, 40, 45, 60)
findInterval(t2, g)
#>  [1] 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

You can save the result of `findInterval()` as e.g. `y` and use `which(y==1)` to find which entries correspond to the first interval.

Answer (score 0):

We can try `cut` + `is.na` like below

```
lapply(
  g,
  function(x) {
    t[!is.na(cut(t, x, include.lowest = TRUE))]
  }
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1]  2  6  8 20

[[2]]
[1] 20 22 30 40
```